# Can't connect to my backend when running Cypress on Github Actions

Tags: reactjs, graphql, cypress, github-actions

I have a React app that I'm testing with Cypress. I then have a separated backend running on Graphql-yoga. Everything works fine locally and testing with Cypress also works flawlessly.

But now I'm trying to use Github Actions for the first time and I have created a job to get my backend, start it, get my frontend and run Cypress. I have a console log with 'Server running on port ...' on my server, and I'm seeing it when the job runs, but still Cypress isn't connecting to my backend and I have no clue why. All Cypress tests but one are failing. The only test that's not failing is one I've created just to make sure the backend isn't sending any response. I don't see any errors/warning related to it.

Here's my workflow file:

```
name: CI

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  cypress:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout backend repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: ****/****
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
          path: backend

      - name: Set up Nodejs ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Install backend dependencies
        working-directory: ./backend
        run: npm install

      - name: Run backend
        working-directory: ./backend
        run: node server.js &
        env:
          APP_SECRET: ${{ secrets.BE_APP_SECRET }}
          FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY: ${{ secrets.BE_FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY }}
          CLOUDINARY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.BE_CLOUDINARY_SECRET }}
          CLOUDINARY_KEY: ${{ secrets.BE_CLOUDINARY_KEY }}
          NODE_ENV: ${{ secrets.BE_NODE_ENV }}
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.BE_DATABASE_URL }}

      - name: Checkout frontend repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run Cypress tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          start: npm start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
          config: baseUrl=http://localhost:3000
        env:
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_NODE_ENV: test
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?
Thanks in advance!